# Firefox not displaying @font-face fonts

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, font-face

I embedded fonts to a website via @font-face. My code works in Chrome and Safari, but not in Firefox and I don't know why. The fonts are hosted by the same domain and I also put them in the root directory already.

That's the code:

```
@font-face {
   font-family: 'Effra';
   src: url('font/Effra-Regular.eot');
   src: url('font/Effra-Regular.otf') format('opentype'),
        url('font/Effra-Regular.svg') format('svg'),
        url('font/Effra-Regular.eot') format('truetype'),
        url('font/Effra-Regular.woff') format('woff');
   font-weight: normal;
   font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: url('font/Effra-Regular.eot') format('truetype'), should it not be ttf?

Comment: Thanks, @wtf8_decode that's right. I changed it but the text looks the same…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your font to:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'Effra';
   src: url('font/Effra-Regular.eot') format('embedded-opentype');
   src: url('font/Effra-Regular.otf') format('opentype'),
        url('font/Effra-Regular.svg') format('svg'),
        url('font/Effra-Regular.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('font/Effra-Regular.woff') format('woff');
   font-weight: normal;
   font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the mistake! I changed it but the text is still not being displayed in the proper font… Any other ideas?

Comment: Are you getting any error output on your console related to the css on Firefox or other browsers?

Comment: Nothing in Firefox. But Chrome says it can't find the ttf, woff and otf files and Safari says it can't find the svg, ttf, otf and woff files. Which is weird because those are the two browsers in which it works and the fonts are at the exact same place as the other formats.

Comment: Check if the font names are actually Effra-Regular and not Effra. Is the "font" folder sitting in the same folder as your css?

Comment: Oh crap that was embarrassing. Sorry and thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Change font extension `.eot` to `.ttf` and include another font file with extension `.ttf`

```
@font-face {
   font-family: 'Effra';
   src: url('font/Effra-Regular.eot');
   src: url('font/Effra-Regular.otf') format('opentype'),
        url('font/Effra-Regular.svg') format('svg'),
        url('font/Effra-Regular.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('font/Effra-Regular.woff') format('woff');
   font-weight: normal;
   font-style: normal;
}
```